# Connecting to mdf database with Web.config ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, localdb, mdf

I tried many things and saw a lot of information on the internet. It just doesn't work and I want to know what am I doing wrong.

I created a .mdf database in my App_Data folder and trying to connect it through Web.config.

my `<connectionString />` looks like this:

```
<add name="Datab1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Datab1.mdf;Database=Datab1; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"  />
```

And I also tried this:

```
<add name="Datab1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                      AttachDbFilename=E:\Secret\Secret\App_Data\Datab1.mdf;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      User Instance=True"/>
```

The `providerName="System.Data.Client" />`gives me an error so I removed it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JamieRees I solved it, solution below here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by going to Server Explorer > Connect to Database > Data source to "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" and Db file name browse to the .mdf file you want to use. Use Windows Authentication.

in the Web.config use this string:

```
<add name="Datab1" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=path\to\folder\of\database\Datab1.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And replace Datab1 with your own database name of course. This worked for me so this question is solved!